# sitemap generator does not work properly / Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sitemap, sitemap-generator-gem

i built a simple sitemap with the gem sitemap generator.
It is supposed to list the job pages of my application. 
E.g. www.mydomain.com/vacancies/24

There is a bug that I cannot fix myself for days:

It shows the wrong indexes (that do not exist). E.g.
www.mydomain.com/vacancies/645
`enter code here`Here is my sitemap.rb file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sitemap_generator'

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "http://www.frankfurtstartupjobs.com"

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do

  Vacancy.find_each do |vacancy|
    add vacancy_path(vacancy), :lastmod => vacancy.updated_at, :priority => 0.5
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure that they do not exist? This shouldn't have anything to do with the sitemap_generator. Check what's the result of `Vacancy.find_each` and double check it agains the actual records in the db.

Comment: Vacancy.find_each  give me the right ones. E.g. job with the id 30. But my sitemap shows. id 640. How do I check it against the actual record in the db??. I thought Vacancy.find_each  gives me exactly that. Or is that something different?

Comment: I mean, you have to be overlooking something. :) Are you sure you generated the sitemap in the correct environment and that you are not tracking it through vcs?

Comment: I generated it via the command "heroku run rake sitemap:install". Is that correct? I mean that should be correct running it via the server right?

Comment: No, you should use `heroku run rake sitemap:refresh`. Here's the doc https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator#rake-tasks

Comment: I initially installed it. But after that also used "heroku run rake sitemap:refresh". But it is still the wrong index.